# Categories for the Working Mathematician, Exercise IV.01.01

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

The problem reads:

Show that Theorem 2 can have an added clause (and its dual):

(iv) A functor $G: A \to X$ and for each $x \in X$, a representation $\varphi_x$ of the functor $X(x,G-): A \to \textbf{Set}$,

where Theorem 2 begins by saying:

Each adjunction $\langle F,G,\varphi \rangle: X \to A$ is completely determined by the items in any one of the following lists.

Now, what I hopefully understand so far is that for each object $x$ in $X$, we have a natural isomorphism $$\varphi_x: A(r_x,-) \to X(x,G-),$$ and I'm supposed to start by constructing a functor $F: X \to A$ so that I can eventually construct a function $\varphi$ for which, for each objects $x$ in $X$ and $a$ in $A$, we have a bijection $$\varphi(x,a): X(x,G(a)) \to A(F(x),a),$$ with $\varphi$ natural in $x$ and $a$. Now, I'm fairly sure that the object function of $F$ will be given by $F(x)=r_x$, but I'm having trouble seeing what the arrow function is supposed to be for each arrow $f: x \to x'$ in $X$.

---

Edit:

Ok, following Qiaochu Yuan's answer, I want to make sure I got everything correct:

Given a functor $G: A \to X$ and for each object $x$ in $X$, a representation $\langle r_x,\varphi_x \rangle$ of the functor $X(x,G(-))$, I define for each object $x$ and arrow $f:x_1 \to x_2$ in $X$, $F(x)=r_x,$ and $F(f)$ the arrow $F(x_1) \to F(x_2)$ given by the natural maps $$X(x_1,x_2) \to \hom(X(x_2,G(-)),X(x_1,G(-))) \cong \hom(A(F(x_2),-),A(F(x_1),-)) \cong A(F(x_1),F(x_2))$$ coming from representability and Yoneda's Lemma. I then define the function $\varphi$ for each objects $x$ in $X$ and $a$ in $A$ by $$\varphi(x,a): A(F(x),a) \to X(x,G(a))$$ $$g \mapsto ((\varphi_x)(a))(g),$$ which is a bijection natural in $x$ and $a$ because $\varphi_x$ is a natural isomorphism.

Comment: There is a small mistake : you have a map $X(x_1,x_2) \to \hom(X(x_2,G(-)),X(x_1,G(-)))$ natural in $x_1$ and $x_2$, but it is not necessarily bijective. The rest looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an application of the Yoneda lemma. I'm going to write $[-, -]$ for hom to save some notation. Under the assumption that $[x, G(-)]$ is always representable by some object $F(x)$, so that $[x, G(-)] \cong [F(x), -]$, we can associate to any morphism $f : x_1 \to x_2$ a natural transformation

$$[f, G(-)] : [x_2, G(-)] \to [x_1, G(-)]$$

by precomposition. Using representability this is a natural transformation

$$[F(x_2), -] \to [F(x_1), -]$$

between representable functors, and so by the Yoneda lemma it is given by precomposition by a unique morphism $F(x_1) \to F(x_2)$; this is the desired candidate for $F(f)$.